# What will be the function for this to be an homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

Consider this problem: Define an equivalence relation ~ on $X =\mathbb{R}^2$ by $(x_1,y_1)~ (x_2,y_2)$ iff $y_1 =y_2$ . Let (X/ ~ ,U) be identification space and let T denote the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that (X/~ ,U) is homeomorphic to $(\mathbb{R},T)$.

The problem is that I am not able to define the homeomorphism . Can you please define the map and give a reasoning why you chose that particular  map?

I am a beginner in this course and classes are online. So, I am a bit weak in problem solving and Trying to learn.

Comment: Can you see what elements of $(X/ \sim,U)$ are?

Comment: @Matt They are Elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with same y  coordinate.

Comment: Hint: Start by finding a continuous function $X\to R$ which is constant on each equivalence class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

The first step for you is to define a function which takes an equivalence class and maps it to an element of $\mathbb{R}$. Once you've done this, the rest shouldn't be too tricky - you need to check that the function is continuous, and define a continuous, two-sided inverse. I'll give some hints about this first step and leave the rest to you.

We'll go step by step. You need a function from $(X/ \sim, U)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let's first inspect this space $(X/ \sim, U)$. Elements of $(X/ \sim, U)$ are equivalence classes; as you say in the comments, an equivalence class here consists of all elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the same $y$ coordinate. To be specific, an element of $(X/ \sim, U)$ therefore corresponds precisely to one particular $y$ coordinate - that is, a particular element of $\mathbb{R}$. Can you see how to define a function of the sort we need, using this information?

Comment: I think $(x_1 ,y_1) = y_1$ is a homomorphism. Am I right ?

Comment: CAn you please reply to my above comment?

Comment: What is $(x_1,y_1)$?

Comment: I mean that $f(x_1,y_1) = y_1$ is the map

Comment: Yes. And what is $(x_1,y_1)$?